# Handle null with C# string Contains in a loop

Tags: c#, list, null

I have data in which i'm getting

```
NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I know it has to do with an intentionally created attempt at making a null in a list.  I'm using linqpad to try and mimic my code

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(null);
list.Add("scorp\\jack");
list.Add("you");

var x = "jack";
var admin = 0;
foreach (var y in list) // Loop through List with foreach.
{
    //Console.WriteLine(prime);
    if(y.Contains(x))
    {
        admin = 1;
    }


}

Console.WriteLine(admin);
```

As soon as it runs over

```
 if(y.Contains(x))
```

Then it cannot handle the null and I wonder what graceful way of handling it would be?

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156)

Comment: you can change your if statement like `if(y != null && y.Contains(x)) `

Comment: @SonerGönül I think this should be an answer, not a comment, because as it looks it fully covers OP's question.

Comment: On second thought, actually, it's possibly a dupe.

Comment: Checking `if( y != null && y.Contains(x) )` is doing just fine as I tried it. I'm really not sure what is the real issue with OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add the null condition to your if statement:

```
if( y != null && y.Contains(x) )  {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @un-lucky would it? how come?

Comment: @un-lucky - There is an && operation so if first condition fails then it will not check the second condition.

Comment: first condition fails, wouldn't it quit the rest of it?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. This is direct, to the point, and correct.

Comment: @un-lucky no, this won't throw in the same way; this will fix the problem

Comment: It doesn't Throws error at all. I tried it. The issue is from the OP i guess :|

Comment: I suggest `foreach (var y in list.Where(y => y!=null && y.Contains(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(null);
list.Add("scorp\\jack");
list.Add("you");

var x = "jack";
var admin = 0;

// Add the Where extension method to filter out null values.
foreach (var y in list.Where(xx => xx != null)) // Loop through List with foreach.
{
    //Console.WriteLine(prime);
    if(y.Contains(x))
    {
        admin = 1;
    }


}

Console.WriteLine(admin);
```

Conversely, you could leave the loop alone and change the `if` to:

```
    if(y != null && y.Contains(x))
```

Comment: I like this solution, because when everyone suggests to check nullness right here and right now, this solution prevents null values in foreach body altogether. Still, it's just one of the alternatives and it can be wrong solution if we would need to handle null values inside loop.

Comment: @CodingFeles meh... adding LINQ just  to check `null`? that is a lot of unnecessary overhead and code confusion for that aim (compared to the nice clean value-typed allocation-free custom list iterator that `foreach` will use on `List<T>` otherwise)...

Comment: @MarcGravell - Code confusion?  It's about as clear and self documenting as it gets.  And the overhead is minimal.  You've got to check for null either way and changing scope, THEN checking for null has to be more expensive.

Comment: the `.Where` bundled onto the end is not exactly the cleanest. As for overhead - how familiar are you with what these two things will be doing under the covers? Iterating a `List<T>` directly is *very* efficient (it has a custom value-typed iterator - it doesn't use `IEnumerable<T>`/`IEnumerator<T>`) - and an in-place `null` check is just a `br_true` / `br_false` - incredibly cheap. To do it with linq requires a *reference-type* iterator and enumerator allocation, a delegate allocation (although reused / cached), and multiple virtual calls and a delegate invoke per iteration step.

Comment: short version: " and changing scope, THEN checking for null has to be more expensive. " is an incorrect assertion

Comment: @MarcGravell, I agree with overhead, but this is the only answer that highlited general preventing null values processing, not just immidiate local check. Thank you for info about `List<T>` custom iterator. Never heard about it, will research this now :)

Comment: @CodingFeles to save you looking: `List<T>.GetEnumerator()` returns a `List<T>.Enumerator`; the compiler will prefer this, ignoring `IEnumerable<T>` etc